# Adding and displaying multiple route overlays in Gmap.Net C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, routes, overlay, gmap.net

I have 3 different overlays in my code where I intend to display the following

1. Route between origin and destination in blue color
2. Sharp right turns along the route in red color
3. Sharp left turns along the route in green color

When debugging the code, I can see all the different overlays (its color alternates between red and green even though they are different overlays) but when the code runs, only the overlay containing the route remains whilst the others disappear. I wonder if it is possible to add multiple overlays on a map?

Comment: Yes it is possible to have multiple overlays.  Can you post your code please?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I found a fix, I just had to add routeIntmap.Stroke = (Pen)routeIntmap.Stroke.Clone(); in my method where I add routes and markers and not it works like a charm